# In Java, is it safe to call Character.isXxx() methods with an int returned from InputStream.read()?

Tags: java, unicode, character, inputstream

When reading a text file, I would like to do something like this:

```
InputStream input = ...;
int read = input.read();
if (Character.isWhitespace(read)) {
    // do something with the whitespace
}
```

The alternative would be to check for a negative `read()` return value (aka, end of input) and explicitly cast:

```
InputStream input = ...;
int read = input.read();
if (read >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace((char) read)) {
    // do something with the whitespace
}
```

However, that involves an extra branch and cast, and I'd like my code to be as efficient as possible, so I'd prefer the first method.

However, I'd like my code even more to be robust :), and I'm not sure whether the first method could create subtle problems. From what I gathered, Unicode defines both `0xFFFF` and `0xFFFFFFFF` as non-characters, so I think it's safe. But what do the experts say?

And just to make sure, question relates to whether my approach is safe for *all* `Character.isXxx()` methods, not just `Character.isWhitespace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InputStream.read()` method reads a **single 8-bit byte** and returns it as a 32-bit `int` in the range of `0x00 - 0xFF`, or returns `-1` on EOF.

The `Character.isXXX()` methods that accept a 32-bit `int` as input expect a **full Unicode codepoint** in the range of `0x00 - 0x10FFFF`.  A single byte *may* represent a full codepoint as-is, if the file consists of 7-bit ASCII characters (where bytes `0x00 - 0x7F` map to codepoints `U+0000 - U+007F`), or ISO-8859-1 (where bytes `0x00 - 0xFF` map to codepoints `U+0000 - U+00FF`).  If the file is using **any** other encoding, there is no guarantee that any given byte will map as-is to a codepoint of the same value, especially if the byte is greater than `0x7F` (most 7/8-bit encodings use the same byte values for ASCII compatibility - but not all do!).

The `Character.isXXX()` methods that accept a 16-bit `char` as input expect a **UTF-16 codeunit** in the range of `0x00 - 0xFFFF`.  A single `char` can hold a Unicode codepoint as-is up to codepoint `U+FFFF`. However, these methods *do not* support UTF-16 surrogates, and so cannot handle Unicode codepoints above `U+FFFF` (which require 2 `char` values to represent them).

So, to answer your question - can you `read()` any given byte from a file and pass it as-is to a `Character.isXXX()` method and get a reliable result? The answer is - **it depends on the file's actual encoding**.  If the file is encoded in 7-bit ASCII or 8-bit ISO-8859-1, then yes.  Otherwise, *maybe*, but typically only for bytes 0x7F, as bytes `0x80 - 0xFF` are encoding-specific and will depend on how the particular encoding maps between bytes and Unicode codepoints (assuming the file is even using a 7/8-bit encoding to begin with).

Comment: I just realized that my question is actually pretty dumb, using `InputStream`s for reading text... Of course I should be using a `Reader`. If so, would that be safe? I guess so, because it then boils down to the question whether the `Character.isXxx(int) methods return `false` for `-1` -- which they do (I experimentally verified that).

Comment: Yes, when reading a text file, you should be using a character-based API, such as `InputStreamReader`, instead of a byte-based API.  However, in order to use such a reader successfully, you have to know the input's encoding ahead of time so you can specify that charset in the constructor. If the input has a BOM for specifying the charset, you have to read the BOM yourself first, as Java does not usually handle BOMs for you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe. For the `0xFFFFFFFF` case, all the isXxx methods return false. Actually, that's true for everything beyond `0x000FFFFF` because those values are undefined in Unicode. For `0xFFFF` it's mostly the same, although `isBmpCodePoint` is true.

Comment: The -1 return value for 'read()` is an out of band value and should not be used for any purpose other than to detect end of stream.